# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't auto-mount DVD drive

Tags: ubuntu, automounting, dvd

For some reason, my Ubuntu has ceased to auto-mount DVD media. I can do manually

```
sudo mount /dev/dvdrw /mnt/dvdrw
```

and mounting happens fine and I can access the media. But it doesn't do it automatically though.

I have no idea when this started to happen because it's been quite long since I used that device last time.